# strFileName in open file dialog

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I am fairly new to c#.

My question is what is strFileName in open file dialog?

I have this code currently:

```
 string input = string.Empty;

        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();

        open.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.* ";

        open.InitialDirectory = "C:";

        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

            strFileName = open.FileName;

        if (strFileName == String.Empty)

            return;
```

It brings up an error on strFileName. i cant find an explanation as to what it does in this code.

Any help will be appreciated and i apologise if this question has been asked before.

Comment: you probably need to rename `strFileName` to `input`, or vice versa.

Comment: Like @muratgu stated, changing strFileName to input is probably what you need to do because currently "strFileName" is not declared and "input" is not used in the code. Otherwise to declare strFileName you would have a line "string strFileName = string.empty;" instead of the line that is declaring input, or you could change the assignment line to "string strFileName = open.FileName;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing what the error is, just by looking at your code, you are probably getting a compile error on strFileName because it is not declared:

You can either change your code to this:

```
string input = string.Empty;

OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();

open.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.* ";

open.InitialDirectory = "C:";

if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

   input = open.FileName;

if (input == String.Empty)

   return;
```

Or this:

```
string strFileName = string.Empty;

OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();

open.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.* ";

open.InitialDirectory = "C:";

if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

   strFileName = open.FileName;

if (strFileName == String.Empty)

   return;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. i see now the problem, strfilename has been replaced with input and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't give me an error - though I did have to declare it. Did you?

```
    string strFileName = "";  // added this line - it compiles and runs ok

    private void TestFunc()
    {
        string input = string.Empty;

        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();

        open.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.* ";

        open.InitialDirectory = "C:";

        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

            strFileName = open.FileName;

        if (strFileName == String.Empty)

            return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need declare strFileName first

```
string strFileName = string.empty();
```

then use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the variable strFilename as a string:

```
string strFileName = string.Empty;
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
open.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.* ";
open.InitialDirectory = "C:";
if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    strFileName = open.FileName;
} 
/* you probably don't want this unless it's part of a larger block of code
if (strFileName == String.Empty)
{
    return; 
}
*/

return strFileName;
```

Comment: ps. I added additional braces after the if statements - they're not needed but personally I find it makes code easier to read / you're less likely to get bugs where code reads differently to how it runs.